# Visio check if shape has a hyperlink

Tags: visio, shapesheet

I have shapes that I want to change the format based on if they contain a hyperlink. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911808/check-if-hyperlink-exists-in-a-shape) question solves this with VBA, but I'm wondering if this is possible with shapesheets only.

It seems to be possible to check if `Hyperlink.Row_1` exists. But as soon as the hyperlink is removed, the `Hyperlink.Row_1` disappears with it, and any formula referencing that row are deleted as well. Even worse: if you add a new link, it's added on `Hyperlink.Row_2`.

So now I'm hoping there's a function that checks for hyperlinks that I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if this is possible with shapesheets only

Sorry, It is impossible without VBA!